# Cron jobs help

Tags: php, cron

I am trying to make a cron job via my websites cpanel. I have talked to the support services and they gave me this command to run to execute a php file on my website.

```
/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/mymcstatus/domains/mymcstatus.net/public_html/redesign/scripts/update.php
```

This doesnt seem to work though, I have also set the minute interval to every minute using */1.

I am using the code below inside of the file update.php:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('log_errors', 1); 
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__) . '/error_log.txt'); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require('minequery.class.php');
include('../config/config.php');

    $date = date("D-M-Y");

    $file = fopen("UPDATE_LOG($date).txt", 'w');

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM servers") or die(mysql_error());

    if($query) {

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

        $ip = $row['ip'];
        $port = $row['port'];
        $name = $row['name'];

        $string = "[UPDATE LOG]: $date - Updated Server $name \n";


        fwrite($file, $string);

        print("[UPDATE LOG] Updated Server $name </br>");



    }

    mail("duncan@mymcstatus.net","UPDATED","Server has updated","From: Mymcstatus");    

    } else {

        print("Cant query");
    }



?>
```

When I go to update.php manually through the web browser that code works, but nothing seems to happen with the Cronjob. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that could be going on here. The first is to check the file permissions of update.php and make sure it is executable. The cron may be executing as a different user that doesn't have permission to execute update.php. The 2nd thing you can try is including this as the very first line of update.php with no whitespace before it.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php
```

Comment: Ok added that no change though.

Answer (score 0):

Usually cron jobs aren't run from the same directory where your PHP lives so it's possible that it is running but the output file is being created elsewhere.  Try changing the output file path to be the full path to the file, i.e:

```
$file = fopen("/home/mymcstatus/domains/mymcstatus.net/public_html/redesign/scripts/UPDATE_LOG($date).txt", 'w');
```

Comment: Ok i did that now when I go there manually it gives me an error. But it also doesnt seem to make Cronjobs work still.

Comment: Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/mymcstat/domains/mymcstatus.net/public_html/redesign/scripts/update.php on line 28

Comment: If $file is a boolean then that means the fopen failed to open that file for writing.  Ensure the output file has valid write permissions and isn't in use by another program.

Comment: Ok how would i change file permissions for a file that is being created

Comment: Try using "$file = fopen(dirname(_\_FILE_\_)."/UPDATE_LOG($date).txt",'w'); and see if that works.  Not sure why it's not allowing you to write to the file when you test via the browser.  To set permissions for a new file you need to set permissions on the directory that will contain the new file - the file will inherit those permissions.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the above comments I managed to fix the file paths but it also came down to the command. I had put the wrong user path in here is the command that works.

```
/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/mymcstat/domains/mymcstatus.net/public_html/redesign/scripts/update.php
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

It's always a good idea to `cd` to your script's path. This way you don't need any change in the name of the `include` and `require` files and any other file names engaging in file operations. Your cronjob command could look like this:

> cd /home/mymcstatus/domains/mymcstatus.net/public_html/redesign/scripts/; /usr/local/bin/php -q /home/mymcstatus/domains/mymcstatus.net/public_html/redesign/scripts/update.php

You don't need to supply any absolute file paths this way.